# Invoke Component in message Enricher and how to define the target value for Message Enricher

Tags: mule

I am practicing on salesforce to mulesoft connection. I am trying to query the account from salesforce, do some logic using Invoke Component and update the Account name in Salesforce. Please find the XML code below. I get the following error when i invoke..

> Execution of the expression "Variable:Fname=__object_for_enrichment" failed. (org.mule.api.expression.ExpressionRuntimeException).

**XML:**

```
<http:listener-config name="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" host="localhost" port="8092" doc:name="HTTP Listener Configuration"/>
    <sfdc:config name="Salesforce__Basic_Authentication" username="username" password="*******" securityToken="Token" doc:name="Salesforce: Basic Authentication" url="https://login.salesforce.com/services/Soap/u/38.0">
        <reconnect-forever/>
    </sfdc:config>
    <spring:beans>
        <spring:bean id="Bean" name="UpdateAcc" class="com.pack.salesforceconnect.SFJava"/>
    </spring:beans>
    <flow name="salesforceconnectFlow">
        <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/salesforce" doc:name="HTTP"/>
        <sfdc:query-single config-ref="Salesforce__Basic_Authentication" query="dsql:SELECT Id,Name,ShippingCity FROM Account ORDER BY Name DESC" doc:name="Salesforce"/>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:input-payload doc:sample="sample_data\Account.dwl"/>
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
    Id: payload.Id,
    Name: payload.Name,
    ShippingCity: payload.ShippingCity
}]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <enricher source="#[payload.Name]" target="#[Variable:Fname]" doc:name="Message Enricher">
            <invoke name="Invoke" object-ref="UpdateAcc" method="ChangeSCity" methodArguments="#[payload.Name]" metadata:id="id"/>
        </enricher>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
%output application/json
---
[{
    Id: payload.Id,
    Name: variable:FName,
    ShippingCity: payload.ShippingCity
}]]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <set-payload value="#[payload]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

**Class:**

```
package com.pack.salesforceconnect;

public class SFJava {
    public String ChangeSCity(String Fname){
        //String ShippingCity;
        System.out.print("Account Name received : "+Fname);
        if (Fname == null){
         Fname = "New Account";
        }else{
            Fname = "Washington Industries Inc.,";
            }
        System.out.print("Account Name: "+Fname);

        return Fname;
        }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Syntax wrong .. it would be `target="#[variable:Fname]"` instead of `target="#[Variable:Fname]"`
Or simply you can use `target="#[flowVars.Fname]"`

Comment: Thanks for your help